# How to get the underlying string of a regular expression in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, string, c++17

I have a string and want to check if this string matches a specified regex. If that is not the case I would like to return a warning to the user that says `string xyz does not match regex abc`.

Example code:

```
std::string func(std::basic_regex rgx, std::string str)
{
    // do stuff 1
    if (!std::regex_match(str, rgx))
    {
        return "String " + str + " does not match the pattern " + std::string(rgx);
    }
    // do stuff 2
}
```

This does not work, since both `std::string(rgx)` and `"some string " + rgx + " more string"` gives an error.

Also `std::basic_regex` does not seem to provide a method to retrieve the underlying string that describes it (see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex)). **What did I miss?**

I am using C++17.

Comment: You're not missing anything.  `std::regex` doesn't provide a way to get what it was constructed from.

Comment: Is there a way to solve the above problem then? Besides of having the caller pass an extra `std::string` which describes the regex?

Comment: huh? do you mean to show the regular expression used, show the regular expression in plain english, or show the string that was used? also you are returning a string from a bool which is not correct and why an error is being thrown. a bool is expected as the return. lastly, if you are trying to get the plain english of the regex which you would need to build a regex parser that parses the regex and outputs what each part is doing.

Comment: @User12547645 AFAIK, that is the only way.  What you could do is make your own `regex` class that wraps `std::regex` and a `std::string`.

Comment: Show the regular expression: If the regular expression is `std::basic_regex{"\d+abc\d[1-3]"}`, and `str="some string", then `func` should return `"String some string does not match the pattern \d+abc\d[1-3]"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica. This does not sound ideal to me, but better than nothing

Comment: @User12547645 well then the problem is you are trying to return a string from a function that returns a bool

Comment: True, the function shoudl return a string. I will fix that

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica if you like you can suggest that as an answer. I will wait a day or two and then mark your answer as a solution, if there is no better way to do this

Comment: @User12547645 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/regex-regular-expression-in-c/ should give you some help

Comment: Most users won't know how to parse a regular expression that has a certain amount of complexity. It's much better to **describe** the expected input than to make users figure out the meaning of a fairly technical (often write-only) string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::regex` doesn't provide a way to get the string from it once it has been constructed.  One way to get around that is to wrap the regex and the string together in a object so you can pass them together.  That would look like

```
class my_regex
{
    std::string str;
    std::regex regex;
public:
    my_regex(const std::string& regex_str) : str(regex_str), regex(regex_str) {}
    const std::string& str() const { return str; }
    std::regex& regex() { return regex; }
};
```

and then you would use it in your code like

```
std::string func(my_regex rgx, std::string str)
{
    // do stuff 1
    if (!std::regex_match(str, rgx.regex()))
    {
        return "String " + str + " does not match the pattern " + rgx.str();
    }
    // do stuff 2
}
```

---

You could make `str` and `regex` conversion operators instead but an issue with that is that a lot of the regex library uses function templates and no conversion is done during type deduction so you would have to explicitly cast, which is more verbose then just calling a member function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is a nice and simple solution. Not what I expected, though. I thought that there is something in the standard that I must have missed

Comment: @User12547645 No problem.  You didn't miss anything AFAIK.  There is a [standard google group](http://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/std-proposals) that you can float ideas in and you could ask about if it would be worth getting this functionality built into `std::regex`.